# Prevent certain profiles from approving accounts

Tags: apex, trigger, approval-process

I have a requirement to prevent certain user profiles from approving accounts. Wrote below trigger which is partially working. However getting below error when a user in Standard User profile tries to approve the record.

> AccountTrigger: execution of AfterUpdate caused by: System.UnexpectedException: Illegal filter on ProcessInstance
>   Class.AccountTriggerHandler.afterUpdateTriggerHandler: line 17, column 1
>   Trigger.AccountTrigger: line 4, column 1

Here is my handler class

```
public with sharing class AccountTriggerHandler {

    public static void afterUpdateTriggerHandler(Map<Id,account> accMapNew, Map<Id,account> accMapOld) {

         Id myProfileId = [Select id, name from profile where name = 'Standard User'].Id;

         set<Id> modfiedAccounts = new set<Id>();
         set<Id> ApprovalNotAllowed = new set<Id>();


         for(account a: accMapNew.values()){
             if(accMapNew.get(a.Id).Active__c != accMapOld.get(a.Id).Active__c && accMapNew.get(a.Id).Active__c=='Yes') {
             modfiedAccounts.add(a.Id);
             }
        }

         list<ProcessInstance> ProcessInstances = [SELECT TargetObjectId,LastActor.ProfileId,LastActor.Name,
                                                       (SELECT Id, ActorId,Actor.Name,OriginalActor.Name,OriginalActor.profileId,Comments,  
                                                        StepStatus,ProcessInstanceId FROM StepsAndWorkitems 
                                                        order by createdDate desc limit 1)
                                                        FROM ProcessInstance where 
                                                        TargetObjectId IN :modfiedAccounts 
                                                        AND LastActor.ProfileId IN (:myProfileId) //problem
                                                        order by createdDate desc limit 1];


        for(ProcessInstance pi: ProcessInstances) {
                 {
                 ApprovalNotAllowed.add(pi.TargetObjectId);

                 } 

        }
        set<account> ApprovalNotAllowedFinal = new set<account> ([Select Id from account where id in :ApprovalNotAllowed]);

        for(account acc :ApprovalNotAllowedFinal) {
            account ac1 = accMapNew.get(acc.Id); 
            ac1.addError('Standard user cannot approve accounts);
         }

    }
}
```

Why do I get this error? How can I fix it?

Comment: Have you tried querying the `Id` of all the `User` records which have that `Profile` and filtering on that `Set<Id>` instead?

Comment: Typing up answer one sec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you try filtering on `LastActorId` rather than `LastActor.ProfileId`. You can get the filter value by adding a subquery.

```
Profile whietelistedProfile = [SELECT (SELECT Id FROM Users) FROM Profile WHERE ...];
Set<Id> userIds = new Map<Id, User>(whitelistedProfile.Users).keySet();

... WHERE LastActorId IN :userIds
```

Comment: That’s exactly what I did after looking at your previous comment. Thanks again.